# wifi issue in Compaq 15-s004TX Notebook

Tags: wifi

My laptop has windows 10 but suddenly I encountered Wifi range issue that means my wifi is detecting wifi about one meter but not above that.I also reinstalled windows 10 but still problem exist.

what should I do?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

Well the first thing to try would be to open up your laptop.  From there you can take a look at the wifi card.  It is possible that there is something obstructing it or its not fully in or anything.

The second option which is likely the one you will have to take is to purchase a cheap usb wifi adapter.  They can be had for around $10 on Amazon usually.  You can get them pretty much anywhere you can buy computers and tech products though.